# Stored procedure performance degradation with MIN and MAX functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, timeout

I have a database table in Production used to store the `workflow` of a given item; each record of the table represents basically the status of an item on a specific date.

The oversimplified table structure is something like this:

**Workflow table**

```
|-------------|------------|---------|----------------|
| Category    | ItemCode   | Status  | InsertDate     |
|-------------|------------|---------|----------------|
|    Cat1     |    Foo1    | 01      | 2012-01-01     |
|-------------|------------|---------|----------------|
|    Cat1     |    Foo1    | 02      | 2012-03-02     |
|-------------|------------|---------|----------------|
|    Cat1     |    Foo1    | 03      | 2012-04-01     | 
|-------------|------------|---------|----------------|
|    Cat1     |    Foo2    | 01      | 2012-04-06     |
|-------------|------------|---------|----------------|
|    Cat1     |    Foo2    | 02      | 2012-05-07     |
|-------------|------------|---------|----------------|
|    Cat1     |    Foo2    | 04      | 2012-05-09     | 
|-------------|------------|---------|----------------|
|    Cat2     |    Foo3    | 01      | 2011-02-03     |    
|-------------|------------|---------|----------------|
|    ...      |    ...     | ..      |....            |    
|-------------|------------|---------|----------------|
```

So, at *2012-01-01* the Item *Foo1* has reached the Status *01*; at *2012-04-01* has reached the status *03* and so on.

The StoredProcedure `PR_GetCategoryItemsInformation`, taking a given `Category` as input, reads the Workflow table and gives a result like this:

@Input: Cat1
Output:

```
|------------------|---------------|------------------|---------------------|
|   Category       |    ItemCode   | DateOfFirstRecord| StatusOfLatestRecord|
|------------------|---------------|------------------|---------------------|
|     Cat1         |     Foo1      |    2012-01-01    |         03          |    
|     Cat1         |     Foo2      |    2012-04-06    |         04          |
```

The SP, given a `Category`, for each `ItemCode`needs to get the first row of the workflow to read the `InsertDate` and the last row of the workflow to get the current `Status`.

It boils down in a SP implementation that looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PR_GetFooItemInformation
    @Category CHAR(3)
AS
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #TabTemp (
            Category CHAR(3),
        ItemCode CHAR(3),       
        Status CHAR(2), 
        InsertDate DATETIME
    )

    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX XIE1TabTemp 
        ON #TabTemp (...)

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX XIE2TabTemp 
        ON #TabTemp (...)

    INSERT INTO #TabTemp 
    SELECT
                 Category,
                 ItemCode,
                 Status,
                 InsertDate   
    FROM Workflow
    WHERE (Some rules to cut down the number of rows)

  SELECT 
      T1.Category,
      Item.ItemCode,
      T1.InsertDate,
      T2.Status
  FROM 
      Item
  INNER JOIN
      #TabTemp as T1 ON Item.ItemCode = Workflow.ItemCode
  INNER JOIN 
      #TabTemp as T2 ON Item.ItemCode = Workflow.ItemCode
  WHERE
      ...
  AND
      T1.InsertDate= SELECT 
                         MIN(InsertDate) 
                     FROM 
                         #TabTemp as T3 
                     WHERE ..
  AND
      T2.InsertDate = SELECT 
                         MAX(InsertDate) 
                      FROM 
                         #TabTemp as T4 
                      WHERE ..
```

The SP has worked as expected for many years (2005), but a couple of months ago it started to give some random timeout; since the number of records of the `workflow` table is growing (2.5M and counting), its performance will surely get worse and worse <sup>*</sup>.

The tables are properly indexed and, for what it's worth, the sql management studio does not suggest any further indexes on the SP.
The same SP without using the temporary table is something like 4x slower.
The temp table at this time, is being populated by an average of 1.5M of rows on each call.

The problem, to my limited dba knowledge, is related to the `MIN` and `MAX` functions that need to be calculated to reach the first and the last row for each item of a given category.

I have omitted several details on the workflow table and on the SP implementation but I hope that what I've described could be enough to get an idea of the problem.

Finally the question:
do you know any sql strategies or even sql-server proprietary solutions to handle this kind of scenario?

What kind of restrictions do I have?
Well, the SP is used on a BackOffice function and should return all the live records and not a preprocessed subset.

<sup>* I'm not a dba; one of the dba is currently studying this little monster in his dark laboratory.</sup>

Comment: Does the table have an id field, a PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Do you know if the slowdown is due to the increase in row in the workflow table, or the number of rows being inserted into your temp table?  It would also be helpful to know the indexes on the table and whether they've been maintained/rebuilt to reduce fragmentation.  Have you looked at an (estimate and/or actual) execution plan for this proc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation that you suggest can be done by a relatively simple query:

```
select category, ItemCode, min(InsertDate) as DateOfFirstRecord,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then Status end) as LastStatus           
from (Select category, ItemCode, Status, InsertDate,
             row_number() over (partition by category, ItemCode order by InsertDate desc) as seqnum
      from workflow w
      where category = <category>  
     )  w
group by category, ItemCode;
```

I realize that this is more complicated once you put in your conditions.

In general, I prefer to have the SQL optimizer choose the best way to execte a query, rather than having temporary tables.  (Having said that, there have been some very unpleasant experiences where I did have to resort to multiple queries because the optimizer chose the wrong plan.)

I suggest that you try this and see if it fixes your performance problem.

Comment: I'm following this hint, soon-ish I will post the result

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to calculate MAX and MIN over date?

You can do for MAX

```
 SELECT TOP 1 InsertDate FROM #TabTemp WHERE ... ORDER BY InsertDate DESC
```

and for MIN

```
 SELECT TOP 1 InsertDate FROM #TabTemp WHERE ... ORDER BY InsertDate ASC
```

and save it to 2 datetime variable.

Comment: Are you sure this will scale better than MIN and MAX? The tables are indexed so I expect to get the same performance with TOP and MAX.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    item
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  MIN(insertDate) AS dateOfFirstRecord
        FROM    workflow wf
        WHERE   wf.itemCode = i.itemCode
        ) fr
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                status AS statusOfLatestRecord
        FROM    workflow wf
        WHERE   wf.itemCode = i.itemCode
        ORDER BY
                wf.insertDate DESC
        ) lr
```

Create an index on `workflow (itemCode, insertDate)` for this to work fast.

Comment: Could you please explain the `Cross Apply` and `Outer Apply` and why this solution will work fast?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx. This will work fast if you have the index as described, because it will need but `O(LOG(N))` logical reads per item.

Answer (score 0):

Is Insert Date an Index? You would need a composite index (category, itemcode, insert date)

Most likely, your bottleneck is in the temp table you are creating unnecessarily. You can use a where condition to filter out your rows.

Is it possible to rewrite your query like this?

```
select category, itemcode, a.InsertDate, b.Status from (
        select category, itemCode, min(InsertDate) minDate, max(insertDate) maxDate
        from table where .. group by categroy, item code) minmax
        join table a on a.category =minmax.category 
                  and a.itemcode=minmax.itemcode and a.insertDate = minmax.mindate
        join table b on b.category =minmax.category and b.itemcode=minmax.itemcode 
        and b.insertDate = minmax.max date) results
```

Comment: Without the temporary table, the SP is 4x slower.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT Category,
       ItemCode,
       MIN(InsertDate),
       MAX(Status)
FROM workflow 
WHERE Category = @cat
GROUP BY ItemCode
```

You might not need the temporary tables. This query would get the desired output. 
INDEX the Category and ItemCode.